# R parallel package parSapply(): cannot print message

Tags: r, apply, lapply, sapply, rparallel

I've been exploring  the parSapply() function in parallel package.

In the sapply() function we can do this:

```
result = sapply(1:10, function(x){print('haha'); return(x)})
```

This prints "haha" in each iteration and stores 1:10 in "result".

When I try to do the same thing using parSapply():

```
cores = detectCores() - 1
cl = makeCluster(cores)
result = parSapply(cl,1:10, function(x){print('haha'); return(x)})
```

Only 1:10 got stored in result but the 'haha's are not printed. Wondering how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: See the `outfile` argument to `makeCluster()`.

Comment: @MartinMorgan Thanks